# Regex in JAVA for 3 or more consecutive consonants checking

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot, swagger-ui

```
public static final String REGEX_NAME = "[^aeiouAEIOU]{3,}";
public static String str = "abbbc";
if(str.matches(REGEX_NAME))
System.out.println("matched");
```

This is matching in any regex editor but does match in my spring boot swagger. But it is matching the string "bbbc" . I mean it can match a whole word but can not match a partial word. How to solve this.

Comment: yes. i want to match consecutive consonants. so i negated the vowel.

Comment: `a` prevents it from matching the whole string, and `String#matches()` requires a whole string match. Use `Matcher#find()`.